# Undefined value for parseInt()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning Javascript events, but I have a problem about the value I type in an input.

When I type a number, the calcul needs to be change (keyup). Same thing about the option that I choose (change).

But the value that I return with my paragraph (id=res) is undifined. I don't understand what it means and how to debug it.

```js
// Here is the Javascript for my events (keyup and change).

document.getElementById("selectDevice").addEventListener('change', change);
document.getElementById("montant").addEventListener('keyup', change);

function change(e) {
  var montant = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("montant").value, 10);
  var selectDevice = document.getElementById("selectDevice").value;
  switch (e.target.id) {
  case 'nothing':
    var resultat = montant;
    console.log(resultat);
    break;
  case 'usd':
    var resultat = montant * 1.14;
    console.log(resultat);
    break;
  case 'eur':
    var resultat = montant * 0.82;
    console.log(resultat);
    break;
  }
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = resultat
}
```

```html
<!-- Here is the HTML -->

Amount: <input id="montant" type="text" />
Device: 
<select id="selectDevice">
  <option id="nothing" value="nothing">Please choose a device</option>
  <option id="usd" value="eur">EUR</option>
  <option id="eur" value="usd">USD</option>
</select>
Convert amount: <span id="res"></span>
```

I'm speaking french, I didn't translate all my code, but if you have some questions, I'm here =)

If you have some solutions from the Javascript Documentation, thank you to give me the page, because I need to learn to search in the doc in order to find my solutions by myself.

Have a nice day =)

Comment: You can debug it by adding `console.log(e.target.id)` and seeing that it is `"montant"` or `"selectDevice"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `switch` statement was looking at the ID of the element triggering it, which has 2 problems:

1. When the element that triggers the change is different, the switch result is different - you want the switch to be relevant to only the select box.
2. The ID doesn't actually matter - it's the value you want to check, and you already have it available as `selectDevice`.

This only needs a tiny fix:

```js
// Here is the Javascript for my events (keyup and change).

document.getElementById("selectDevice").addEventListener('change', change);
document.getElementById("montant").addEventListener('keyup', change);

function change(e) {
  var montant = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("montant").value, 10);
  var selectDevice = document.getElementById("selectDevice").value;

  switch (selectDevice) { // changed this and that was it.
  case 'nothing':
    var resultat = montant;
    console.log(resultat);
    break;
  case 'usd':
    var resultat = montant * 1.14;
    console.log(resultat);
    break;
  case 'eur':
    var resultat = montant * 0.82;
    console.log(resultat);
    break;
  }
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = resultat
}
```

```html
<!-- Here is the HTML -->

Amount: <input id="montant" type="text" />
Device: 
<select id="selectDevice">
  <option id="nothing" value="nothing">Please choose a device</option>
  <option id="usd" value="eur">EUR</option>
  <option id="eur" value="usd">USD</option>
</select>
Convert amount: <span id="res"></span>
```

Comment: I really need to learn more about switch statements.. Thank you for your help =)

Comment: It's basically just a shorthand for `if (a == b) {...} else if (a == c) { ... } else if (a == d) {...}`, where you can stick `a` at the top, and `b`, `c`, `d` lower and save some code + add a little readability.